# jQuery-Validation-Engine in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, jquery-validation-engine

I used jQuery-Validation-Engine v2.6.1 for my web form and it works great in Firefox.  I just tested it in Internet Explorer 10 and validation is not working at all.  I noticed on the index.html file included in the package it states it supports (IE 6-8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera 10).

Is there an update or anything to make it work in IE 9 & 10?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this meta to your head section

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
<![endif]-->
```